# "element is not attached to the page document" error Python Selenium while scrolling

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

while scrolling to send a message to my contact list on Instagram, after scrolling said 6 to 10 times and sending messages to around 40 of my contacts, the script quit with an error message "element is not attached to the page document"
and this happened every time I execute the script

```
def go_to_inbox():
    try:
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/direct/inbox/")
        time.sleep(float(config["TIMETOWAIT"]))
        div = WebDriverWait(driver, float(config["TIMETOWAIT"])).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "_abyk")]')))
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(div).perform()
        try:
            file = open('contacts.txt', 'w')
        except IOError:
            input("Could not open file!")
        scroll = 0
        while scroll < int(config["SCROLL"]):
            links = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div._ab8s a')
            for link in links:
                if scroll >= int(config["SCROLL"]):
                    break
                if check_if_user_already_contacted(link.get_attribute('href')):
                    file.write(link.get_attribute('href') + '\n')
                    file.flush()
                    link.click()
                    time.sleep(float(config["TIMETOWAIT"]))
                    send_message()
                    scroll += 1
                    print(scroll)
            links.clear()
            driver.execute_script(
                "arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", div)
            time.sleep(float(config["TIMETOWAIT"]))
        file.close()
        os.remove("contacts.txt")
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
```

every time I sent a message to one of my contacts I added him to the contacts file

Answer (score 0):

You don't really specify in which line the error appears but a random guess is that it needs a higher wait time to load all elements in order to access them.